# Place column values in lagged combination

Tags: r, data-structures

I am trying to solve problem with f(t)=f(t-1)+f(t-2)+f(t-3).....+f(t-n) combination in a dataframe. Based on **Target(f(t)) column** values in the given data,I must be able to place rest of values in consequent columns.I need some R codes to attain this combination.

I have provided data below in codes and screenshot(INPUT):

```
data<-data.frame(id=1:5,
             target=c('b','a','c','d','e'),
             col1=c('e','b','e','b','a'),
             col2=c('d','e','a','c','d'),
             col3=c('a','d','b','e','c'),
             col4=c('c','c','d','a','b'))

output<-data.frame(id=1:5,
              target=c('b','a','c','d','e'),
              col1=c('e','b','a','c','d'),
              col2=c('d','e','b','a','c'),
              col3=c('c','d','e','b','a'),
              col4=c('a','c','d','e','b'))
```

The expected result is shown in screenshot(OUTPUT).

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7vWO.png)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJSKO.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The following uses base R only and does what you want.

```
cols <- grep("^col\\d+$", names(data), value = TRUE)
inx <- seq_along(cols)
res <- sapply(rev(inx), function(i){
    n <- seq_len(i)
    new <- c(as.character(data[["target"]])[-n], as.character(data[["target"]])[n])
    new
})

colnames(res) <- cols
res <- cbind(data[1:2], res)

identical(output, res)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach with `base R` using `embed`

```
data[3:6] <- head(embed(rep(data$target, 2), 4)[-1,], 5)
data
#  id target col1 col2 col3 col4
#1  1      b    e    d    c    a
#2  2      a    b    e    d    c
#3  3      c    a    b    e    d
#4  4      d    c    a    b    e
#5  5      e    d    c    a    b
```